# Where should an ISR be declared in a library?

Tags: interrupts, avr-gcc

Suppose I have a library consisting of TWI.h and TWI.c which contains an ISR defined according to AVR-GCC syntax. For example:

```
ISR(TWI_vect)
{
   switch(TWCR)
   {
       ...
   }
}
```

Should the ISR code go into TWI.h or TWI.c? Or should I put the full ISR in TWI.c and put some sort of ISR "prototype" in TWI.h?

Comment: Generally, any executable or memory consuming code should go into the `*.c` files. There are cases it is not like that, but they should be well justified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ISR belongs in the `.c` file. It's a function that directly generates code that's linked into the executable (that is, it isn't an inline-only function), so that's where it goes.

The ISR shouldn't be called by other functions, so it does not need a declaration in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

Too minimize scoping issues, only those referenced by a calling party should be in the header.

Your Isr is generally not called by others so make it private to thee .C files IS thee way to go.

What I generally do is to insert a call back function in there soon that the user can install his own Isr.